# How to bind to Label showing 1 to 10 of 39 entries to label in Jquery data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

[enter code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0sSp.png)How to bind to Label showing 1 to 10 of 39 entries to label in Jquery data-table

[reference below Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETyEz.png)

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

How do I bind to a label showing 1 to 10 of 39 entries to label in a jQuery data table?

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMkDX.png)

https://qphs.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-3d0b2ed63854cf2dcddc046f2a1c0d18

Answer (score 0):

You can change dom positioning of datatable. Refer [DOM positioning](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html) and [DOM](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom).

```
Example:


<div id="myId">
<!--DIV to display total rows-->
</div>

<table id="example">
</table>

 $('#example').DataTable( {
     //"dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
     "dom": '<"#myId"i>lfrtip'
 );
```

Comment: but i required to bind outside of jquery data table. NOTE: jquery data table down is required and top is required in another div

Comment: need to display bottom and Up (label in another DIV)